# issue when pushing data to vector in loop

Tags: c++, arrays, file

This is my `txt` file where first line is number of `dataSets`. 2nd line(size1 variable) is equal to number of elements in 3rd line(A1 array) and 4th line(size2 variable) is equal to number of elements in 5th line(A2 array). My readFile function have to overwrite variables and arrays listed above without overwriting `dataSets` variable.

My `countElementsInArray` function is to count the number of occurrences of digits from the array `A2` in array `A1`. My program works for one dataSet(5 lines in txt) but when it comes to for example 3 dataSets(13 lines) my readFile function stops during pushing back results to vector named counts. My question is why it is incorrect and how to replace it?

txt:

```
3
4
-5 -1 0 8
7
7 9 2 0 -7 2 -5
4
1 2 3 4
2
1 1
5
0 0 0 0 0
1
3

Result for above input should be:
Dataset1:
0 0 0 1 0 0 1
Dataset2:
1 1
Dataset3:
0
```

```
int main() {

    int dataSets = 0, size1 = 0, size2 = 0;
    std::fstream file;
    openFile(file);

    int *A1 = new int[size1];
    int *A2 = new int[size2];

    readFile(file, dataSets, size1, size2, A1, A2);
}

void readFile(std::fstream &file, int &dataSets, int &size1, int &size2, int *&A1, int *&A2) {

    std::vector<int> counts;

    file >> dataSets;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataSets; i++) {
        file >> size1;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size1; j++)
            file >> A1[j];

        file >> size2;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++)
            file >> A2[j];

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            int searchValue = A2[j];
            counts.push_back(countElementsInArray(A1, size1, searchValue));
        }

        int numberOfDataSet = i + 1;
        std::cout << "Dataset" << numberOfDataSet << ":" << std::endl;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            std::cout << counts[j] << " ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}



int countElementsInArray(int *A, int size, int searchValue) {

    int count = 0, first = 0, last = size;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    while (first <= last) {
        int mid = first + (last - 1) / 2;

        if (A[mid] == searchValue) {
            count++;
            do {
                if (A[mid + i] == searchValue && A[mid - j] == searchValue) {
                    count += 2;
                    i++;
                    j++;
                } else if (A[mid + i] == searchValue) {
                    count++;
                    i++;
                } else if (A[mid - j] == searchValue) {
                    count++;
                    j++;
                }

                return count;
            } while (A[mid + i] == searchValue || A[mid - j] == searchValue);
        } else if (searchValue < A[mid])
            last = mid - 1;

        else if (searchValue > A[mid])
            first = mid + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @anastaciu man this is described in the easiest way

Comment: This means code that can be copied to a compiler and can reproduce the problem as you describe it, creating a sample of your code that reproduces the problem may not be easy, I find that by doing that, a fair amount of times you can track the problem youself.

Comment: Removing the `countElementsInArray`  function didn't help, https://godbolt.org/z/pfFERP

Comment: You deny yourself.
'The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem.'

Comment: @anastaciu i added main function

Comment: You should rewrite your question, it is very difficult to understand **what** are you trying to do in this code. It will allow us to better understand the problem and your code.

Comment: One problem that stands out is `int *A1 = new int[size1];`  `int *A2 = new int[size2];` being `size1` and `size2`  equal to 0, essentially you have a fixed size array with 0 size, it cannot hold any value, so this `file >> A1[j];`and this`file >> A2[j];` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem that stands out is

```
int *A1 = new int[size1];
int *A2 = new int[size2];
```

being `size1` and `size2` equal to `0`, essentially you have a fixed size array with `0` size, it cannot hold any value, so this

`file >> A1[j];`

and this

`file >> A2[j];`

are both [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Changing `size1` and `size` to `10` just to test it, hields a result.

Sample:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/ra2AE4uff74NXAXp

When the previous code hielded an ugly crash:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/tHGK8unYj0ww9KSe

I think from here you can correct the rest of your program.

Replacing

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
     std::cout << counts[j] << " ";
}
```

With:

```
for(auto& i : counts)
   std::cout << i;
```

Will show you all the elements in the array, which I gather are not correct, you must adjust data collection from the file so that the sizes are correct, and initialize A1 and A2 inside the function with the correct sizes.

Note that the definition of `openFile();` is still missing, I assume that it's just to open the file.

Comment: it is very strange because i understand my mistake now but my IDE show me the same result despite this i assigned 10 to size1 and size2

Comment: What happens in you IDE, are there errors? Is the result faulty?

Comment: i debugged it and everything goes well but when vector tries to push_back it doesnt happen. is it normal that online compiler do it well?

Comment: printing the vector like that, It's still undefined behaviour bcause you are accessing th vector out of bounds, to avoid this it's better to use a for each loop I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: ok thank you, but can you explain what means that vector is out of bounds when i printing it in my case? I am not printing anything beyond vector size.

Comment: @javastudent, I think you can fix it from here, I now have to go, but tomorrow I'll check if you need more help.

Comment: @javastudent, it was a hunch, but it seem that you don't print any out of bounds values, when two compilers present a different output it's a classic sign of UB, did you copy the code exactly as it is in the online compiler? You can also check if the file is indeed being opened.

Comment: yes, the code is exactly the same. unfortunately when i create arrays inside function after passing size1 and size2 from file to variables i also get the same result.. :/

Comment: @javastudent `dataSets` variable is also failing, try to assign it a manual value, I'll pass by tomorrow to see if you already solved all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

@anastaciu i changed code a little bit and now i can see in debugger that program is passing counts to vector counts but i still cant display it

```
void fread(std::fstream &file, std::vector<int> &A1, std::vector<int> &A2) {

    std::vector<int> counts;
    int dataSets, size1, size2, x, y;
    file >> dataSets;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataSets; i++) {
        file >> size1;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size1; j++) {
            file >> x;
            A1.push_back(x);
        }

        file >> size2;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            file >> y;
            A2.push_back(y);
        }

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            int searchValue = A2[j];
            counts.push_back(fcount(A1, size1, searchValue));
        }

        int numberOfDataSet = i + 1;
        std::cout << "Dataset" << numberOfDataSet << ":" << std::endl;
        for(auto& k : counts)
            std::cout << k;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```